# Grafana JSON Explorer API

Tags: json, api, grafana

I woulk like to construct a panel in Grafana (following this tutorial: https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin/) and use this JsonExplorer class (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/packages_api/ui/jsonexplorer/#constructor-jsonopenconfigkey) for displaying and navigating through a JSON tree.
This class has a render method (which returns a HTMLDivElement) but when I use it as show in the sample code below, it throws the following error:

```
Type 'HTMLDivElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type 'HTMLDivElement' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props
```

Extract of my sample code is:

```
    export const SimplePanel: React.FC<Props> = ({ options, data, width, height }) => {
  const traces = '[{"firstName": "John","lastName": "Doe"},{"firstName": "Mark","lastName": "Spree"}]';

      const jsonTraces = JSON.parse(traces);
      const jsonExplorer = new JsonExplorer(jsonTraces, 0);
      const jsonHTML = jsonExplorer.render();
    
      return (
    
          <div>{jsonHTML}</div>
      );
    };
```

Does anyone have some sample code that shows the usage of this class for creating a custom panel? Many thanks - Christian